# change image-border on mouseover

Tags: html, dhtml

i have a problem, i'm working on a gallery php script and need help, i have a picture, it has a lightgray border around, and if theres a mouseover event, i want the border to turn gray. how can i do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the :hover pseudo class. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        IMG.HoverBorder {border:5px solid #eee;}
        IMG.HoverBorder:hover {border:5px solid #555;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="HoverBorder" src="test.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works well on all sane browsers I have access to. If you need IE 6 support, take a deep breath and [check this out](http://locusoptimus.com/css-trickery/ie-image-border-styles-on-hover-solution.php) (thanks to @Brian Kim for reminding me about IE6):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a:hover{ background-color:white; }
        a:link img, a:visited img{ border:5px solid #eee; }
        a:hover img{ border:5px solid #555; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#"><img class="HoverBorder" src="03 messed up status log edit IE6.png" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

There are several variants on this approach--I suggest you click through to that site for other options that might be more suitable to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:hover](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_hover.asp) pseudo-class.

For example:

```
<style>
a.bordered:hover img {
   border: solid 2px grey;
}
</style>

<a href="..." class="bordered"><img src="..." /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use .mypictureclass:hover to apply the border.

but also apply a transparent border to the picture display class to avoid it jumping when the border is added.

Answer (score 0):

okay dudes i've got it XD as i said, i'm a html guy, and i just found out how it works, it used a CSS as style, so i tried much things, and, surprise, i just made a copy of the imagethumbnail-tag and changed the bordercoler and edited the title to imagethumbnail:hover

thank y'all as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CCC;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FC3;
}
a:img,
a:link img,
a:visited img,
a:focus img,
a:hover img,
a:active img {
    border: none;
}
</style>
```

The code follows everything I've seen so far, but still isn't displayed in IE correctly & shows borders around the images. This is a sample of one of the mouseover images.

```
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/buttons/home.png" alt="Home" width="216" height="44" 
        onmouseover="this.src='images/buttons/home_.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/buttons/home.png'"></a>
```