# Change CSS border colors with links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the border around my links to change color with the links. I have it set so `a.hover` changes the color slightly and wanted to make it change the border color also. Is it possible to do this using just CSS and HTML?

This is my HTML code:

```
<h1>
    <a class="border" href="http://example.com">Home</a>
    <a class="border" href="http://example.com/forum">Forum</a>
</h1>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
h1 {
text-align: center;
color:#00F;

}
a:link {
color: #00F;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00F;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #006;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
a.border {
border-style: solid;
border-color: #00F;
border-width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `a.border:hover{border-color:#F00;}` etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [change image-border on mouseover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466449/change-image-border-on-mouseover)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I clean the code:

```
<h1>
    <a href="http://example.com">Home</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/forum">Forum</a>
</h1>​

    h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color:#00F;
}
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #00F;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 5px solid #00F;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #006;
  border: 5px solid #006;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}​
```

Use Border and I've delete class in tag html.

http://jsfiddle.net/SUMEk/

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to add `border: 5px solid #000000;` inside your `a:hover{}` I think

- This won't work unless you remove the `border` class on your `<a>` tag or add the above inside `a.border:hover{}` - read the comments for an explanation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vJ2fJ/1/ - your `.border` class prevents this, I'll find a good link to explain why in a sec - for now though a.border:hover{} will work

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the css property "border". The following code will add a border when you hover:

```
a.border:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #006;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

Your a.border was more specific than your a:hover selecter. Therefore you wouldn't see a border.

JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vJ2fJ/2/

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need is this:

```
a.border:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
```

The other styles are already inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ":hover" pseudo selector if you want the style to change when the user pass the mouse over your item. Your CSS should be like this:

```
a:hover {
    border:5px solid #00F;
}
```

When you hover any link you'll se the effect.

Answer (score 1):

```css
a.border:hover{
    border-color: #006; /*Or whatever*/
}
```

I'd advise reading up on http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/